# Open Audio Database of English Letters

Tags: english, audio

I have embarked on a project to gather spoken english letters into a free and open database. I call it the [English Alphabet Audio Database](http://robertmassaioli.bitbucket.org/alphabet-upload.html).

My question is simple: does any other such database already exist? I could not find one which is why I made this one but I wanted to be doubly sure and I thought that this community might be able to help.

Comment: By letters, you don't mean letters of the alphabet but correspondence and such like (ahh, blessed disambiguation). If the latter, you might consider radio programs for which transcripts exist.